# Why can't I  update to iOS 5 my iPod Touch 4th gen?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I am trying to upgrade my 4th gen iPod touch to iOS 5.
First I downloaded the IPSW file from iTunes.

When I press <kbd>shift</kbd> + "Restore" button, I get the following error:

> The iPod cannot be restored at this time because the iPod software update server could not be contacted or is temporarily unavailable.

What can I do to prevent that? I have looked into the iPod update logs and see that I am getting error 1602 but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: iTunes can't connect to Apple's servers. If your internet works, then check your hosts file and make sure TinyUmbrella (or equivalent) didn't add an entry redirecting it to Cydia's servers. If it has, just delete the entries and try again.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to be connected to the internet to validate the install iOS packages with Apple's servers at the time of the restore. It is part of the install process that confirms to apple that your software has installed correctly and it generates the user license rather than asking you to enter a serial number for you allowing you to use the software.

Specifically for Error 1062 you need to remove iTunes and Apple Mobile device support from you applications. Then install the latest version of the software on your PC/Mac.

Comment: I also connected to the internet.

Comment: If this has failed there could be something wrong in iTunes, to repair you will need to reinstall, download and install iTunes again, stay connected to the internet and then plug your iPod in once the new verison is installed.

Comment: Thanks, now i hot about that.and when i upgrade iOS 5,in the middle the following numbers of iTunes appeared and not finished update.
iTunes Error 1602.How can i solve that?

Comment: If you get error 1062 you need to remove iTunes and Apple Mobile device support from you applications. Then install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have Tiny Umbrella installed, make sure to untick "Set Hosts to Cydia on Exit" under the Advanced tab! If you did use it and don't have it anymore, open /etc/hosts and add a # in front of

```
74.208.10.249  gs.apple.com
```

so it reads

```
#74.208.10.249  gs.apple.com
```

Comment: Isn't Tiny Umbrella running on the iPhone/iPod? The error described in the question happens on the computer running iTunes.

Comment: Tiny Umbrella runs on the computer that is supposed downgrade iDevices.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you see seems to be different from error 1602. To recover from error 1602, please have a look at [this Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694), especially [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694#error1602) section, and follow the proposed steps.